# Angular ui-router 'ui-view' vs 'data-ui-view'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I've been looking through examples of the AngularJS ui-router and I have seen a couple of different directives that accomplish the same thing.

The most typical example I've seen:

```
<div ui-view>...</div>
```

But I've also seen: (MeanJS)

```
<div data-ui-view>...</div>
```

**What is the difference between `data-ui-view` and `ui-view`?**

I tried looking for a custom directive defined in the MeanJS code but was unable to find any.
(The MeanJS code in reference was generated by running `yo meanjs`)

Comment: `data-` just prefixes with data attribute to make it a valid html. There is no other difference, they both are just the same directive.

Comment: Thanks:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive